# Why is my command throwing a 'data tag parsing failed' error?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to lock some boxes in a map of mine, and I used this command:

```
/blockdata 10 4 9 {Lock:Elyiana's Mage Key}
```

At first it worked, but then when I logged back on the next day it gave me this error message:

```
Data tag parsing failed: Expected '}' but ''' at: {Lock:Elyiana'<--[HERE]
```

I don't know why it doesn't like the apostrophe in the key's name. I would change it, but it already worked and locked some other items. My version is 1.12, does anyone have an answer to my problem?

Comment: Have you tried surrounding the name with quotation marks?

Comment: Try using a backslash

Answer (score 3):

As of 1.12 you have to encase Strings containing special characters (including spaces and apostrophes) with quotes (`" "`).

```
/blockdata 10 4 9 {Lock:"Elyiana's Mage Key"}
```

This should do the trick.